# How to configure remote resource with Artemis cluster?

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Trying to connect our WildFly instance to our remote ActiveMQ Artemis cluster. I don't understand what pieces of the documentation I need to put together to get the correct setting. My currently untested setting:
`broker.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-broker-0" socket-binding="remote-broker-0"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-broker-1" socket-binding="remote-broker-1"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-broker-2" socket-binding="remote-broker-2"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" scheduled-thread-pool-max-size="20" thread-pool-max-size="128"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-broker" entries="java:/RemoteJmsXA java:jboss/RemoteJMSXAConnectionFactory java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-broker-0 remote-broker-1 remote-broker-2" thread-pool-max-size="80" transaction="xa" user="${env.ACTIVEMQ_USER,application.activemq.user}" password="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD,application.activemq.password}" max-pool-size="80" enlistment-trace="true" statistics-enabled="true"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-broker-non-xa" entries="java:/RemoteJms java:jboss/RemoteJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-broker-0" thread-pool-max-size="80" user="${env.ACTIVEMQ_USER,application.activemq.user}" password="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD,application.activemq.password}" max-pool-size="80" enlistment-trace="true" statistics-enabled="true"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-broker-0">
        <remote-destination host="${env.ACTIVEMQ_HOST,application.activemq.host}" port="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PORT,application.activemq.port}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-broker-1">
        <remote-destination host="${env.ACTIVEMQ_HOST,application.activemq.host}" port="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PORT,application.activemq.port}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-broker-2">
        <remote-destination host="${env.ACTIVEMQ_HOST,application.activemq.host}" port="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PORT,application.activemq.port}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

For the broker we are using `jgroups` for broadcast and discovery. My understanding is I can configure this for the `pooled-connection-factory` as well. The [examples](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/clusters_overview#configure_discovery_groups_on_the_client_side) in the documentation leave out how to configure the discovery groups though.

Is this possible? It seems I am missing some fundamental information here, but not sure where to look. Also found this on [pooled-connection-factory](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/13.0/subsystem/messaging-activemq/server/pooled-connection-factory/index.html). It mentions the discovery-group param, but I don't find anything on how to use it for remote connections.

EDIT: My question is, how can I use JGroups discovery here instead of adding an entry for each node in the Artemis cluster?

This works for the JNDI lookup at least:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
  <bindings>
    <external-context name="java:global/remoteContext" module="org.apache.activemq.artemis" class="javax.naming.InitialContext">
      <environment>
        <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
        <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="${env.ACTIVEMQ_URL,application.activemq.url}"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory" value="${env.ACTIVEMQ_URL,application.activemq.url}"/>
      </environment>
    </external-context>
  </bindings>
  <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

`jgroups-ping.xml` (from Artemis cluster):

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd"
>
  <TCP bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr:site_local}"
       bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port:7800}"
       external_addr="${jgroups.external_addr}"
       external_port="${jgroups.external_port}"
       thread_pool.min_threads="0"
       thread_pool.max_threads="200"
       thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>
  <RED/>

  <dns.DNS_PING
      dns_query="message-broker-ha-ping-svc"
      dns_record_type="${DNS_RECORD_TYPE:A}"/>

  <MERGE3 min_interval="10000"
          max_interval="30000"/>
  <FD_SOCK2/>
  <FD_ALL3 timeout="40000" interval="5000"/>
  <VERIFY_SUSPECT2 timeout="1500"/>
  <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"/>
  <UNICAST3/>
  <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                 max_bytes="4M"/>
  <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"/>
  <UFC max_credits="2M"
       min_threshold="0.4"/>
  <MFC max_credits="2M"
       min_threshold="0.4"/>
  <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"/>
</config>
```

But this **doesn't** work for the `pooled-connection-factory`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
  <server name="default">
    <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
    <jgroups-discovery-group name="remote-broker" refresh-timeout="10000" jgroups-channel="activemq_broadcast_channel"/>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-broker" entries="java:/RemoteJmsXA java:jboss/RemoteJMSXAConnectionFactory java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" discovery-group="remote-broker" thread-pool-max-size="80" transaction="xa" user="${env.ACTIVEMQ_USER,application.activemq.user}" password="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD,application.activemq.password}" max-pool-size="80" enlistment-trace="true" statistics-enabled="true"/>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-broker-non-xa" entries="java:/RemoteJms java:jboss/RemoteJMSConnectionFactory" discovery-group="remote-broker" thread-pool-max-size="80" user="${env.ACTIVEMQ_USER,application.activemq.user}" password="${env.ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD,application.activemq.password}" max-pool-size="80" enlistment-trace="true" statistics-enabled="true"/>
  </server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: What's not currently working with the multiple connectors?

Comment: BTW, if you want to use a `discovery-group` from the `pooled-connection-factory` you just need to configure one that matches the broadcasting configuration of the cluster you're connecting to. If you're cluster is using JGroups then you should create a `jgroups-discovery-group` that references a `jgroups-channel` that will receive updates from the remote cluster.

Comment: @JustinBertram thank you for your input again! The above configuration works. However, now we have to modify the `standalone.xml` every time we add or remove another node from the cluster. I was looking for help on how to use discovery groups here, but I believe you already answered that in your second comment. I will give it a go and come back.

Comment: This is a bit confusing and I am not sure where to look... Found this for Jboss 7.4: https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/jboss_enterprise_application_platform_continuous_delivery/19/mgmt_model/subsystem/messaging-activemq/jgroups-discovery-group/index.html but the documentation here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/configuring_messaging/clusters_overview#configure_discovery_groups_on_the_client_side doesn't mention it.

Comment: Artemis Cloud is configured to use JGroups with `dns.DNS_PING`. By default JBoss uses `kubernetes.KUBE_PING`. I found an option to overwrite via environment variable but I fail to understand how to configure this properly. `KUBE_PING` should work, but I need to add the labels for the pod and I don't know where.